# How to put plugin short code in wordpress tmplate rather than in post or page?

Tags: php, templates, plugins, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to put plugin short code in woocommerce template named as "woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php". Plugin short code is as "[products_slider cat_slug="" number_posts="50" show_cats="no" show_price="no" show_buttons="no"]". How can i put it? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

That should help you out, I think. For you, it would be:

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[products_slider cat_slug="" number_posts="50" show_cats="no" show_price="no" show_buttons="no"]');
```

Comment: Very Nice @DiederikvandenB i do not have enough reputation otherwise i must vote you.

Many thanks.

Comment: its working. Please guide me one more thing.
I want that slider at each category page should show images of only that category. Right now its showing images of all categories.
You can see here as a example http://www.rgcowboycustoms.com/product-category/clothing/square-scarves/patterned-show-scarves/

Comment: According to this link (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/wooslider-woocommerce-product-slideshow/), you can just include `category=""` in your shortcode. Inside the loop, you can get the category id by `the_category_ID();`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Kinldy have a look may it help you to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

function woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description() {
  if ( is_tax( array( 'product_cat', 'product_tag' ) ) && get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ) {
   $description = apply_filters( 'the_content', term_description() );
 
         $cat = the_category_ID();
         
                      echo do_shortcode('[products_slider cat_slug="" number_posts="50" show_cats="no" show_price="no" show_buttons="no"]');

   if ( $description ) {
    echo '<div class="term-description">' . $description . '</div>';
   }  

  }

Comment: You have to include the `$cat` var in your shortcode. Try something like this:
 ```<?php

 function woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description()
 {
  if (is_tax(array(
   'product_cat',
   'product_tag'
  )) && get_query_var('paged') == 0) {
   $description = apply_filters('the_content', term_description());
   $cat = the_category_ID();
   echo do_shortcode('[products_slider category="'. $cat .'" cat_slug="" number_posts="50" show_cats="no" show_price="no" show_buttons="no"]');
   if ($description) {
    echo '<div class="term-description">' . $description . '</div>';
   }
  }
 }```

Comment: @Davissonravian, the original problem is solved and you can [**mark this answer as correct**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have *another* question, please [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), thanks.

Comment: Yes you great man. You really help me a lot. I am new at stackoverflow dont know many things here in sense of usage.

Comment: As Brasofilo says: please mark the answer as correct.